# Block number of request using spring webflux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I currently have below reactive service exposed using spring boot 2(Spring webflux)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono taskForUserV1(@RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) String userId,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> userData) {
return service.taskForUserV1(userId, userData);
}
```

But i want to throw an exception to the client requesting my service if the request are lets say more than 500. How to do it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what is "request are let's say more than 500"?

Comment: Clients concurren request consuming the rest service

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at Rate Limiter design pattern implemented by resileince4j @ https://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/#_rate_limiting

```
RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.ofDefaults("testName");

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RateLimiterCallAdapter.of(rateLimiter))
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
        .build();
```